# Switch elements with media queries

Tags: javascript, css

I don't known if it's possible to switch two HTML elements when visiting a website from a tablet.

Now I have the following setup:

```
<section id="content"></section><!-- End section#content -->
<aside id="sidebar"></aside><!-- End aside#sidebar -->
```

What I want is that when you view the website on tablet that the aside position above the content section, like so:

```
<aside id="sidebar"></aside><!-- End aside#sidebar -->
<section id="content"></section><!-- End section#content -->
```

What's the best solution for this? A simple line of `CSS` or do I have to use `Javascript` and how should it looks like.

Comment: This is not possible with css (for now) take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161674/responsive-design-rearrange-element-positions-with-css/15162175#15162175

Comment: Is the `aside` in the desktop mode on the left/right of `section`?

Comment: @Marcel Left is the section `#content` right the sidebar.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you want by css:
Just float `#content` and `#sidebar` by default and remove the float in tablet mode.
Additionally you can set `width: 100%` in tablet mode.

Have a look at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sj43S/2/).

Arrange html like you want it in tablet mode:

```
<aside id="sidebar"></aside><!-- End aside#sidebar -->
<section id="content"></section><!-- End section#content -->
```

And basic css:

```
#content {
    float: right;
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
}

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    #sidebar, #content {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
   }
}
```

You can also add another media query to scale down the desktop mode before switching to tablet mode with relative width. For example like in this [alternative fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sj43S/5/).

Comment: Upvoted for a simple solution which doesn't require large js libraries!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with jQuery.

```
 $('#content').clone().insertAfter('#sidebar');

 //You will also have to remove the first content element. 
 //You could do something like this to remove it

  $('#content').eq(0).remove();

  //or this 

  $('#content:first-child').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ckhGe/

Comment: I try this with label and input. Input code is first then label will position in the markup. When I use your code. The second input field will duplicate... What does I wrong? @Kris Hollenbeck

Comment: Well I am not entirely sure I understand what you are asking. But it sounds like you are cloning the wrong element. Basically how it works is `.clone()` copies the element you want to move. And then `.insertAfter()` will insert the copied element after the desired element. And `.remove()` will remove the copied element.

Comment: So it sounds like you are trying `$('input').clone().insertAfter('label');` Keep in mind, if you have multiple inputs it will clone all inputs as `$('input')` selects all inputs. If you want to select a specific input then you need to either use an id or jquery to select that specific element.

Comment: Yes sorry it works now. One question left. Is it possible to do this online for mobile screen (320px width)  and for the other reset this thing.. @Kris Hollenbeck

Comment: Yes you would just need to do something like `if (screen.width < 320){ // do something } else if(screen.width > 321px){ //do something else }`

Comment: Ok, but how can I reset. Because when I make the browser window bigger, the label positions at the top of the input but I want then that this is first input and then label...

Comment: Also I have now this code: http://snippi.com/s/rc3l1ea But it doesn't work.. When I check the site on a mobile device..