# CSS Flexible Box Layout on iPad

Tags: ios, css, ipad, flexbox

I'm trying to get a very simple layout using the flex model working on iPad.

I have a containing div that is supposed to center the content divs.

The sample code does as intended across all browsers and platforms EXCEPT on the iPad (retina).

Using various iPad emulators online will not replicate the problem. I've only been able to replicate it on the actual iPad.  Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

Any and all advice will be appreciated very much.

CSS:

```
.container { 
width: 510px; 
height: 310px;
background: red; 
display: flex; 
display: -webkit-flexbox;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
flex-direction: row; 
flex-wrap: wrap; 
-webkit-box-pack: center; 
-moz-box-pack: center; 
-ms-flex-pack: center; 
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center; 
-webkit-flex-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items:center; 
border: 2px solid;
padding: 5px;
margin: 0;
}

.content {
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background: green; 
border: 2px solid;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.content2 {
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background: blue; 
border: 2px solid;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Content</p>
</div>
<div class="content2">
<p>Content2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're missing some properties from the old 2009 draft (or have them named wrong).  Your container CSS should look like this:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/ci9imeed

```
.container {
  width: 510px;
  height: 310px;
  background: red;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Note, however, that none of the browsers with a 2009 Flexbox implementation (Android, older Safari, older Firefox) support wrapping.

Comment: Thank you cimmanon. However, looking at ur example on the ipad, the content divs are still not centered...

Comment: It's the floats on the child elements that are the culprit.  According to the spec, float is supposed to be ignored on flex items, but it causes weird things to happen in Webkit's 2009 implementation.  Use `display: inline-block` instead for your fallback.

Comment: Can you get it aligned using inline-block? I'm right now testing on a retina, ipad3, and ipad1. Can't get it on either...

Comment: Terribly sorry cimmanon. Ur answer worked! I was missing the -moz-box property. Thank you! Been pulling hair over this.

Comment: Hi cinnamon. 
I checked your cssdeck example on an iPad 3 (os 6.1.3) and the divs are not centered..
Is this some known issue?

Comment: I don't have a way to test on that device, but I am not aware of any reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: @sangil iOS 6 doesn't have support for display flex. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox